# Django {%trans%} not working, despite django.po being generated

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a template file `templates/admin/base_site.html` which includes one `trans` tag: `{% trans "Event List" %}`.

`settings.py` includes:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'sv'
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/srv/mysite/locale/',
)
```

The Django-admin pages are correctly translated into Swedish, apart from the text in the `trans` tag.

When I run `python manage.py makemessages -l sv` it correctly generates a `locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` file, whose last few lines are:

```
#: templates/admin/base_site.html:9
msgid "Event List"
msgstr "Event List"
```

I then change it to:

```
#: templates/admin/base_site.html:9
msgid "Event List"
msgstr "Händelselista"
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver` again, the string is not translated on the web page.

The rest of the admin page is still translated into Swedish, as it was before.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` added to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.po` files are only meant for editing purpose. You must compile them to `django.mo` files so that they are interpreted:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

See also [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#compiling-message-files).

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the webserver? It won't be serving the newly compiled po files if you haven't.

**Edit:** and be sure to restart Django server after you do as well.

Comment: I wrote that I was running the server with `python manage.py runserver` which implies that I am not using Apache/Nginx yet.